# Moved renderer in lwjgl rendering

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, rendering, lwjgl

I have made a simple application in lwjgl and created simple gui. For now I have frame and panel. But there is a problem.
Because (Display 800x600) when I make panel on Panel(x,y,w,h) (0,0,64,64) everything works fine, but when I create it on other position (x,y where point 0,0 is in left upeper corner) it render moved panel.
[image: Capture of rendering]
The white space is my panel which should change color when I drag mouse on it. It is created on (417,417,64,64), but it's rendered on somethink like (90,90).
I have rendered fonts to show all of itss positions. The blue box I draw on this image is where it should be and it looks like there the panel is, because the white space is changing color when I drag mouse there, but this white space should be there.
My code looks like that:
I am adding all components to HashMap like Panels.

```
glColor3f(backgroundColor.getRed(), backgroundColor.getGreen(),
                backgroundColor.getBlue());
        if (hasFocus()) {
            glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
        }
        glPushMatrix();
        glRecti(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        glPopMatrix();
```

And initGL method:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
        glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 0.0, 40.0);
        glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: are you sure `Display.getWidth()==800 && Display.getHeight()==600`?

Comment: Yeah. I confirmed it with sysout in loop. It is 800x600. Also it's reading my mouse correctly, cause coordinates are ok(also cheked by calling sysout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glRecti doesn't work that way it expects the coordinates of the corners

so instead you should do:

```
glRecti(getX(), getY(), getX()+getWidth(), getY()+getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how it's working that it was drawing somethink else